# how to purposely fail "fopen"

Tags: c++, file, fopen

I need to purposely fail the "fopen"-ing of a file to test my code. How do I do that. My code so far:

```
void MeshTrian::init (std::string filename)
{
    if (!sofa::helper::system::DataRepository.findFile(filename))
    {
        msg_error() << "File '" << filename << "' not found." ;
        return;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");
    bool status;
    msg_error_when(!(status=f))<<sofa::helper::message::UnableToOpenFile(filename.c_str());
    if (status)
    {
        readTrian (f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give it a file that doesn't exist, which may not work in your case depending on how your `findFile` method works.

Comment: exactly... so a file with same name should exist but should get some error while opening it. I tried compressing the file and stripping ".tar.gz" extension. It didn't work :(

Comment: You might need to change file permissions so that you have *write* permission, but not *read* permission. That way `findFile` will (hopefully) work, but the `fopen` won't.

Comment: @user3386109 sounds promising.. while changing perimission through gui(ubuntu 16.04), for "Owner: Me", I get option of only  "Read-Only" and "Read and write". How do i change it to "none".

Comment: FILE* f is not a bool type, you are assigning a file pointer to a bool type, it looks all wrong, you should be checking 'f' not 'status' in your condition.

Comment: `chmod uga-r filename`

Comment: It's easier through a command line. See @MatteoItalia's comment.

Comment: If you need it for unit-testing, you might want to replace `fopen()` with a stub.